# Take away (when ordering food): is it 带走 or 打包?

Tags: characters, expressions

I was told that when you are ordering food you can say either 带走 or 打包.

However, when you are not ordering food and you mean "take this away", then you use 拿走。

Is there a difference in context or meaning between 带走 and 打包?

Comment: If you're in Hong Kong, "带走" is more suitable. Because in the old days, Hong Kong people use 打包 to describe "packing a dead body" so 打包 has a bad meaning. Maybe today the young in Hong Kong aren't aware of it, but it's better to avoid it.

Comment: consecutive use: jukuu:9.  Waiter, we can't finish our meal. Please give us a doggie bag.
 侍者,我们吃不完。麻烦打包带走,
 
watchers of television series about crime are familiar with police officers pronouncing 带走 as a command to other police (guards) to take a prisoner away (back to their cell from the interrogation room)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

In my experience (Beijing), 带走 means take away or take out. 打包 means you want a doggy bag.

Update: As a result of further observation, I've found that both 带走 and 打包 mean take away. However, if you want a doggy bag you would probably say 打包.

Comment: In Taiwan, 帶走 and 外帶 are often used interchangeably.

Answer (score 6):

带走 or 打包 and 拿走 refer to the degree of care required regarding your "takeaway."

带走 (carrying away) or 打包 (wrap it up) means, "I'm taking this home, please treat it with care."

拿走 means "get rid of it." (I don't care how you treat it.)

Answer (score 3):

So far as I know, the difference is simply a matter of region. In my experience 打包 is more common in central and southern China, and 带走 is more common in the north.

They are interchangeable however, and I personally don't know any situations where one is different from the other.

Hope that helps!

Comment: In the KFC in Dalian, Liaoning, the waiter will usually ask “带走 还是 在这吃”, then you can answer “带走”. I usually say "打包" -- when I am full but there are still some food on the table -- to ask the waiter to provide a box or something so that I can bring the food left home.

Comment: So maybe in my city, we usually say 带走 when ordering food, while 打包 is used after the meal.

Answer (score 2):

打包是带走的必要条件，除非你想吃不了兜着走。

打包 is a necessary condition of 带走, unless you like to put your remnant food into your pocket:p

Answer (score 1):

As a native speaker and Chinese teacher, I would say 带走 and 打包 are interchangeable. Usually after a meal in a Chinese restaurant, it is appropriate to either say 不好意思,我要带走 （Excuse me, I'd like to take leftover to go）or 请帮我打包 （Please wrap the leftover up for me）

Answer (score 0):

You should use 走街 in hk. Once i said 打包 and the woman got upset with me. It means wrapping the dead in hk, don't use it under any circumstances unless you want to make the person upset.

Comment: The correct term is 行街. e.g. 奶茶行街 (milk tea, take out)

Answer (score 0):

- 带走 [dài zǒu]
- take away 带走，拿走，取走；
- carry off 夺去；获得；使丧命；成功地处理；
- spirit 精神；心灵；情绪；志气；烈酒；鼓励；鼓舞；诱拐；
- walk off  离开；带走；用散步消除；
- go away with 带走……；与……一同离开
- 打包[dǎ bāo]
- 1.Packing items. Packing and packing;Baling press.
- 2.When you eat in a restaurant, you can wrap it up or put it in containers for taking away.

Answer (score 0):

dǎ bāo 打包 means to pack， dài zǒu 带走 means to take away.
Normally Chinese people would say 打包.

qǐng bāng wǒ bǎ zhè gè cài dǎ bāo 请帮我把这个菜打包
Please help me to pack this dish

If you really want to say 带走，you should say 打包带走，you can't only say 带走 without 打包.
For example：
zhè ɡe cài,wǒ yào dǎ bāo dài zǒu 这个菜，我要打包带走
This dish, I want to pack and take away

Comment: The video is a reference to the answer, so it should be allowed, However, your affiliation with this video impeached its credibility, therefore, I have to remove it

Comment: If you want to post a  video link in your answer, please disclose your affiliation with the video (you can do that by editing your answers)